# Apache ISIS: Set HTTP-Response

Tags: java, http, isis

I have the following situation:
When someone calls my Restful-Service Apache the Apache isis code is predifened accordingly to the request. If you miss some parameters you will get a `400 - Bad Request`. Otherwise when all parameters are given you will usually get a `200 - OK`. But sometimes I want to response a `201 - Created` or `202 - Accepted`.
I didn't find a solution for this problem in the Apache ISIS documentation, and I didn't find a code example in the www.

So could anyone help me here?

Thanks

Edit:
I found this url `https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/master/core/viewer-restfulobjects-server/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/restfulobjects/server/resources/DomainServiceResourceServerside.java`.
There static methods from the `Responses` class is used to create some 2xx statuses, but only `200 - OK` and `204 - No Content` could be created within this class. For all other non-2xx status codes a `RestfulObjectsApplicationException` is thrown.
Is this the right way to respond http codes to the caller?
And how can i respond for example a 202 status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long and short of it is that Apache Isis implements the [Restful Objects spec](http://www.restfulobjects.org/), and the latter doesn't define these status codes.  So there is currently no way to return a 202.

I think that 202 might make sense for a background command, ie one that is annotated to run in the background using [@Action(commandExecuteIn=BACKGROUND](http://isis.apache.org/guides/rgant/rgant.html#__code_commandexecutein_code).

What semantics do you see that 202 should represent?

Meantime, I've raised a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-1639) to capture this conversation.

Thx
Dan

Comment: 202 was only an example. Maybe there is some reason to return a 403 status or something else. But if there is no possibility to return other codes, then I have to implement it the restful objects spec way.

But maybe for 202 is that some processes are put into a queue and are processed later on (if other processes in queue has been processed).